# The below code is working for others but not for me

Tags: php, html

When i try to search something in form it shows me error with all variables...

```html
<form action="search.php" method="get">
     <input type="text" size="25" name="search" placeholder="search this site">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"></form>
    <?php
     include("includes/connect.php");
      if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
       $search_id = $_GET['search'];
       $query = "select * from posts where post_title like '%search_id%'";
       $run = mysql_query($query);
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
       $post_id = $row['post_id'];
       $post_title = $row['post_title'];
       $post_image = $row['post_image'];
       $post_content = $row['post_content'];
     }
     ?>
      <h2>
       <a href="pages.php?id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
        <?php echo $post_title; ?></a>
      </h2>
     <center><img src="images/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" width="100" height="100"></center>
      <p align="justify"><?php echo $post_content; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
```

i think the problem is with loop function. but don't know how to resolve this...

Comment: Show the error message(s) in your question

Comment: which error is getting when you run this code ??

Comment: also can I recommend using `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is depreciated and will not be updated any more.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you've also got the code to output results outside of your while loop, which means that you're only ever going to print out one result, or a set of warnings if there are no results found

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the $-sign in your statement:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_title` like '%$search_id%'";
```

Btw: Don't use mysql_query anymore, its deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead. :)

You're also vulnerable for mysql injections. Try to escape the `$_GET` value: mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search'])

Also, you're overwriting your variables in your while loop, because the call to the variables is outside the while loop. Put those variables inside the while loop like this:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_image = $row['post_image'];
    $post_content = $row['post_content'];
?>
<h2>
    <a href="pages.php?id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a>
</h2>
<center>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" width="100" height="100">
</center>
<p align="justify">
    <?php echo $post_content; ?>
</p>
<?php 
    }//<--- this one closes the while loop
    }//<--- this one closes the if statement
?>
```

Comment: @John it says undefined variable $post_id undefined variable $post_title undefined variable $post_image undefined variable $post_content

Comment: i am new to coding, don't know many things. but i want to learn and this is my first project in php :)

Comment: @684425 Check if your query is good: replace `$run = mysql_query($query);` by `$run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Issue is resolved now. i don't know how to put code in comment here. if someone guide me, i would like to share the corrected code. and thanks all of you for your help. :)